# DbSet<> Does not Contain A Definition For 'ToListAsync()' Although I'm Using .NET 3.1 with EF Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

So I tried to add async methods to my routes and to the interfaces, repositories etc and I coded everything properly. Everything looks great but when I try to run the app I get that error:

`Error CS1061: 'DbSet<Hotel>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Hotel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)`

I downloaded EF Core package and even hard coded most of the things since .NET does not detect anything related to async methods.

Do you know why I get this error?
I could not find any solutions. EDIT: I'm on a Mac btw.

Comment: have you added the using namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-5.0 This is for efcore 5.0 and previous versions, since after 5.0, looks like they are in `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Yes I did. It's even detected by VS mac. I mean it's not grayed out. So it should work I guess. But yeah it just does not.

Comment: when that happens, it means the required assembly is not referenced (a namespace can be defined in multiple assemblies), the required assembly in your case is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll`. Some other projects in your solution may define that namespace making a feel that it's from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` but looks like it's not.

Comment: So the app is working right now. After waiting for a while, it started to warn me to add the namespace System.Threading.Tasks. I hard coded that at first but it was not any help and I came here. You know the rest. now the app solved it by itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The `ToListAsync` function is an extension method defined in the EntityFrameworkCore package. You will need to add a `using` statement like the following:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this example. Putting for NOOBS like me.

```cs
using ApiApp.Data;
using ApiApp.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApiApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public UserController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AppUser>>> GetUsers()
        {
            var users = await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
            return users;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AppUser>> GetUser(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?